# Prevent Autologin after registration on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, registration

I found this code below to prevent auto-login; however, after adding this code, it resets the password of the newly registered user, and when the admin approves the user, the newly registered user cannot log in using the password they created during registration:

```
/**
 * WordPress function to prevent autologin
 */
function user_autologout(){
            wp_logout();         
        }
add_action('user_register','user_autologout');

/**
 * WordPress function for redirecting users on logout. If user comes from registration page, they are directed to a page telling them that their membership request is pending. 
 */


function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'inscription') !== false){
    wp_redirect( home_url().'/pending_registration/' );
    exit(); 
    }
    else{
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
    }
}
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
```

Support on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Imran